# Creating an ARIMA model with Specified Lags and differencing in R

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive-models

Hello I just finished the ARIMA Models in R course in Data Camp and would like run some ARIMA models.
the course used the `astsa` for ARIMA modeling.

For this question I will using the `sunspots` data though the data does not matter for the question

My packages

```
library(astsa)
```

Some data

```
Sun.ts <- sunspots
```

This function with run an AR(12) model with all the lags AR1 though AR12

```
sarima(Sun.ts, p = 12, d = 0, q = 0)
```

How can I do an AR or even a ARIMA model with say just 12th lag or 1 and 12?

Eventually for a project I will be doing a ARIMA model that should look something like this

```
sarima(my_data, p = c(12), d = c(1, 12), q = c(1, 12))
```

Where the model is only including those lags in parenthesis. I have done it in SAS but I want to do it in R.

SAS Code that is model I want to do in R

```
proc arima data=my_data;
   identify var=Deaths(1, 12);
   estimate  p = (12) q = (1) (12) noint method=ml;
run;
```

Comment: I figured out how to do parameter selection with the `fixed` argument in `sarima` function but for the differencing that might need to be done by hand. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hello for the `sarima` function you need to use the `fixed` argument to specify which coefficients you want.

That is done by making a vector of NAs and not NAs.
So for example I wanted a AR(1,12) model so I would need to make a vector that looks like this. With NA is the 1st index and NA in the 12th index. The last index being for the constant and if there is not a constant it needs to be blank.

```
fixed_constant   <- c(NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NA,NA)
fixed_noconstant <- c(NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NA) #No Constant
```

Then use the `sarima` function.

```
sarima(Sun.ts, p = 12, d = 0,q = 0, fixed = fixed_constant, no.constant = F)
```

[image: ttable for AR(1,12)]

Then without the constant

```
sarima(Sun.ts, p = 12, d = 0,q = 0, fixed = fixed_noconstant, no.constant = T)
```

[image: ttable for AR(1,12) no constant]

I created an helper function to make parsimonious ARIMA models. This can be easily extended for the `sarima.for`

```
psarima <- function(tsdata, p, d, q, no.constant = FALSE){

pt = max(p)
qt = max(q)

pvector<- rep(0,pt)
qvector <- rep(0,qt)
for (i in p){
  pvector[i] <- NA
}
for (i in q){
  qvector[i] <- NA
}
if (no.constant == T | d > 1){
  intercept <- NULL
} else{
  intercept <- NA
}
parameters<- c(pvector,qvector,intercept)
sarima(tsdata,pt,d,qt, fixed = parameters, no.constant = no.constant)
}
```

p for parsimonious sarima.

In action
This is an ARIMA with AR(12) and MA(2,3).

```
psarima(Sun.ts,c(12),0,c(2,3), no.constant = F)
```

[image: AR12 and MA2,3]

I am still learning about ARIMA models but for some reason doing this doesn't work.

```
psarima(Sun.ts,1,2,c(2,3), no.constant = F)
```

```
Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]
```

Which I am not sure what is happening to make that occur. It has to do with differencing though.

Comment: Does anyone know an easier way of making parsimonious ARIMA models. Perhaps in another package?